# using MSBuild.ExtensionPack.FileSystem.File Replace on vdproj

Tags: regex, msbuild, vdproj, msbuildextensionpack

Im trying to replace the ProductName held inside a Visual Studio setup project by performing a regex on the file in my msbuild script. To do the regEx replacement Im trying to use [msbuild extension pack](http://msbuildextensionpack.codeplex.com/) and in particular its File task. The target inside my msbuild script looks like this:

```
<Target Name="CustomiseMsi">
<PropertyGroup>
  <RegExPattern>
    <![CDATA[(?:\""ProductName\"" = \""8:.*)]]>
  </RegExPattern>
  <RegExReplacement>
    <![CDATA["\"ProductName\" = \"8:MyApp v1.0\""]]>
  </RegExReplacement>
  <RegExOutput></RegExOutput>
</PropertyGroup>

<MSBuild.ExtensionPack.FileSystem.File
  TaskAction="Replace"
  RegexPattern="$(RegExPattern)"
  Replacement="$(RegExReplacement)"
  Files="@(AbsolutePathToVdProjToParse)">
</MSBuild.ExtensionPack.FileSystem.File></Target>
```

When this target runs I get the following output, but the file remains unchanged.

```
CustomiseMsi:
  Processing File Collection
Processing File: C:\pathHere\mySetup.vdproj
```

Am I going about this right way? Has anyone done regex updated on a vdproj (or anything else) in this manner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this same issue and after trying a few things, I got this to work...

```
<MSBuild.ExtensionPack.FileSystem.File TaskAction="Replace" 
    TextEncoding="ASCII"  RegexPattern='"ProductVersion" = "8:.*"' 
    Replacement='"ProductVersion" = "8:$(Version)"' 
    Files="%(Solution.DeploymentProject)"/>
```

This will simply replace the ProductVersion string with the version that I have in my Solution.DeploymentProject variable.

I dont believe you need to mess with CDATA at all.

Comment: Won't the replacement be made too late to end up in the .msi?